# Registering/Authenticating user with LinkedIn android library on private server

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am creating a REST webserver where users can register with an Android app. To bypass the tedious process of filling out a registration form I am supporting the option to login with LinkedIn Android library.

The LinkedIn Android library offers a unique ID, identifying the user and an access token to talk with the API directly from the app.

I am currently storing the unique ID on my own server, so I know what profile should be loaded with the user that used Linkedin to sign up.

However, I cannot verify the validity of the access token or the id. How do I know that the user passing his ID is actually the real user and not someone else who is using the ID of a different user?

Isn't this a big security risk from LinkedIn?